# How do I generate URL by term_id

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, uri

I have a **taxonomy term ID** that I would like to generate the the URL alias for. In other words, instead of `/taxonomy/term/{id}` I would like to get the alias I have defined for this, eg: `/some/path/myawesometerm`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: short answer, in twig: `{{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': term_id}) }}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are calling "URL aliases" are referred to by Drupal 8 as "path aliases."

The `path.alias_manager` service ([`\Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Path!AliasManager.php/class/AliasManager/8.2.x)) allows to lookup path aliases.

```
$aliasManager = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager');
// The second argument to getAliasByPath is a language code such as "en" or LanguageInterface::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE.
$alias = $aliasManager->getAliasByPath('/taxonomy/term/' . $term_id);
```

But what use is a path alias? The end result is probably to put it into a link render element. [`\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.7.x) should also be a valid option as that will translate into any path alias anyway. It is not exactly clear from the API documentation that it does this, but it does.

```
$link = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => 'Taxonomy term ' . $term_id,
  // Passing in 'language' key as the third option is preferable here so that a language-dependent alias can be found.
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', ['taxonomy_term' => $term_id])
];
```

Comment: Also, from twig: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates

Comment: Took the liberty to add the bit about "URL alias" really being "path alias".  Knowing the proper term helps finding additional info easier.  And I fully agree with the second part; you almost never need the explicitly generate a path in Drupal 8; passing around a Url object almost always works and will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to combine the answers of @Kevin and [this article](https://createdbycocoon.com/knowledge/getting-taxonomy-term-url-path-reference-field-twig-drupal-8), you can directly do it in twig without the need of further logic:

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': term_id}) }}">
  <span>{{ your_label }}</span>
</a>
```